# Perl: replace consecutive digits with their count

Tags: regex, perl, string, replace, digits

My first questions here.

I have a string of digits like `55111233`

as you can see 5 is consecutive twice, 1 thrice 2 once and 3 twice.

I want it to be replaced into `52132132`

in general `number1<count>number2<count>...numbern<count>`

Please guide me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 $digits = "55111233";
 $digits =~ s/((\d)\2*)/$2 . length($1)/ge;
 print $digits;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$str =~s/(\d)(\1*)/$1.(length($2)+1)/eg;
```

Comment: Subtle precedence bug; try with $str="9999999999";